# Print count of repeat tag once

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML file:

```
<limitCheckApproved>
<correlationId correlationIdScheme="tttt">SEF_correlationId</correlationId>
<sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
<party id="party1">
        <partyId>CLIENT1</partyId>
    </party>
    <party id="party2">
        <partyId>BARCGB2L</partyId>
    </party>
    <party id="clearingBroker1">
        <partyId>DB</partyId>
    </party>
    <party id="DCO">
        <partyId>LCH</partyId>
    </party>
    <party id="ExecutionFacility">
        <partyId>SEF1</partyId>
    </party>
</limitCheckApproved>
```

This is my XSLT file:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements= "*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="limitCheckApproved/correlationId">

        <FPCorID>
          <xsl:attribute name = "FPCorIDSch">
            <xsl:value-of select = "correlationId/@correlationIdScheme"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select = "correlationId"/>
        </FPCorID>  

      </xsl:template>   

      <xsl:template match = "limitCheckApproved/party">

      <FpNoOfPartyIDs>
           <xsl:value-of select="count(/limitCheckApproved/party)"/>
      </FpNoOfPartyIDs>

       <FpPartyID>
        <xsl:value-of select = "@id" />
       </FpPartyID>

       <FpPartyIDValue>
         <xsl:value-of select = "partyId" />
       </FpPartyIDValue>

      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
<limitCheckApproved>
<FPCorID correlationIdScheme="tttt">SEF_correlationId</FPCorID>
<FpNoOfPartyIDs>5</FpNoOfPartyIDs>
    <FpPartyID>party1</FpPartyID>
    <FpPartyIDValue>CLIENT1</FpPartyIDValue>
    <FpNoOfPartyIDs>5</FpNoOfPartyIDs>
    <FpPartyID>clearingBroker1</FpPartyID>
    <FpPartyIDValue>CM1</FpPartyIDValue>
    <FpNoOfPartyIDs>5</FpNoOfPartyIDs>
    <FpPartyID>LimitsHub</FpPartyID>
    <FpPartyIDValue>Traiana</FpPartyIDValue>
    <FpNoOfPartyIDs>5</FpNoOfPartyIDs>
    <FpPartyID>ExecutionFacility</FpPartyID>
    <FpPartyIDValue>SEF1</FpPartyIDValue>
    <FpNoOfPartyIDs>5</FpNoOfPartyIDs>
    <FpPartyID>DCO</FpPartyID>
    <FpPartyIDValue>LCH</FpPartyIDValue>
</limitCheckApproved>
```

What I need is that FpNoOfPartyIDs tag be printed once only while the other tags   FpPartyIDValue and FpNoOfPartyIDs to be printed as normal.
But i could not find a correct way to specify this.

I have tried a few ways to do this:

```
.
.
.
<xsl:if test = "partyId = 'party1'">
 <FpNoOfPartyIDs>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(/limitCheckApproved/party)"/>
 </FpNoOfPartyIDs>
</xsl:if>
.
.
```

But this method can led to errors later.

Also I have tried to do everything inside a single template:

```
<xsl:template match="limitCheckApproved">
  <limitCheckApproved>
  .
  .
  .
   <FpNoOfPartyIDs>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/limitCheckApproved/party)"/>
   </FpNoOfPartyIDs>

   <xsl:for-each select = "party">

   <FpPartyID>
    <xsl:value-of select = "@id" />
   </FpPartyID>

   <FpPartyIDValue>
     <xsl:value-of select = "partyId" />
   </FpPartyIDValue>

    </xsl:for-each>
   </limitCheckApproved>
</xsl:template>
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, the output that you show us is **not** the output received when running your code. Specifically, the `FPCorIDScha` attribute is empty and the `sequenceNumber` element is copied to the output.

I guess you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="correlationId">
    <FPCorID FPCorIDSch="{@correlationIdScheme}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </FPCorID>  
    <FpNoOfPartyIDs>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(../party)"/>
    </FpNoOfPartyIDs>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="party">
    <FpPartyID>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
    </FpPartyID>
    <FpPartyIDValue>
        <xsl:value-of select="partyId" />
    </FpPartyIDValue>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which will produce this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<limitCheckApproved>
   <FPCorID FPCorIDSch="tttt">SEF_correlationId</FPCorID
   <FpNoOfPartyIDs>5</FpNoOfPartyIDs>
   <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
   <FpPartyID>party1</FpPartyID>
   <FpPartyIDValue>CLIENT1</FpPartyIDValue>
   <FpPartyID>party2</FpPartyID>
   <FpPartyIDValue>BARCGB2L</FpPartyIDValue>
   <FpPartyID>clearingBroker1</FpPartyID>
   <FpPartyIDValue>DB</FpPartyIDValue>
   <FpPartyID>DCO</FpPartyID>
   <FpPartyIDValue>LCH</FpPartyIDValue>
   <FpPartyID>ExecutionFacility</FpPartyID>
   <FpPartyIDValue>SEF1</FpPartyIDValue>
</limitCheckApproved>
```

If you don't want the `sequenceNumber` to be copied, add another template to suppress it:

```
<xsl:template match="sequenceNumber"/>
```